# get run time error after porting from qt4.8 to qt5.2

Tags: qt4, qt5

i write a project with qt4.8.4 . now i want to porting my project to qt5.2. 
after porting my project to qt5 , i run my app and get this error

> QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break -- Size mismatch for type 'QPaintBufferCacheEntry' [1024]. Previously registered size 0, now registering size 16.

Can someone help me?
 thanks a lot

Comment: It's usually a ODR issue. Are all of your translation units seeing the same definition of that class? Are you using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` / `qRegisterMetaType` on that type in yoru code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem is solved. this is happened because i used opencv libs in my project and compiled it with qt4. i rebuild opencv with qt5 and now everything is ok